# How to write entities query linq?

Tags: linq

I wrote this query to create a new database by copying from an old database and inserting into the new one.  I want this query to change entities. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi.In fact, I've researched about linq, but I've had problems writing in the query. Can you help me to translate my query?

Comment: Please show what kind of trouble you had to clarify what you're trying to achieve. You description is pretty vague. LINQ is for querying, not for inserting data. Also, what's wrong with the current code?

Comment: Hi. My goal is that I created a database.I created the database to combine the same tables that are located in the old database.So I add the values in the old table to the new table.So in the current query I have written, insert the desired tables in the table StudentDatabaseName into the StudentChatabaseDescriptionName with the inscript.In the Settings.Default.Student field, I specified the tables.I want to copy using entity.How can I do it?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*